# Is it possible for an increasing continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ not to be H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuous at some point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on the domain $[0,\infty)$, such that  $f$ is strictly increasing and $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. It seems to me that, at any point $a$, in a neighborhood $U$, $f(x)-f(a)$ has to be *dominated* by something like $(x-a)^\alpha$, for some $\alpha>0$, at any point, i.e. I suspect that this kind of functions will be H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuous at any given point (maybe with different $\alpha$ s). But I cannot materialize this intuition of mine using some formal mathematical techniques.

> Is it possible for $f$ *not* to be H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuous at some point? If it is not possible can anyone give me a hint to the techniques that might be helpful addressing this kind of question?

**In case such an example do not exist, please do not give a full answer**, but give hint to possible methods that I have to learn so that I can address this question myself. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** By the way, note that at any point where the functions is differentiable and the derivative is finite, the functions is automatically Lipscitz continuous at that point. Also, I suppose, though I am not sure, the points where the functions has one of its Dini derivatives finite, it is Lipscitz at that point. Thus the main points of interest are the points where the function is not differentiable and also the Dini derivatives blow up, which I think leave us the only possibility as the point $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try something like

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n x^{1/n}$$

for suitable positive constants $c_n.$

Comment: Oh, right, this is not H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuous whenever $c_n$ is a strictly positive sequence. Nice example!

Comment: Well you have to make sure it's continuous.

Comment: Yes, basically I have to choose such a sequence $\{c_n\}$, that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^{1/n}$ converges $\forall x>0$, right?

Comment: I suppose a sequence like $1/n^2$ will suffice as most of the terms of $x^{1/n}$ will become very close to $1$ for large $n$, and then the $1/n^2$ will make the sequence converge. Actually any sequence like $1/n^r,\ r>1$ will do. The series will converge by comparison test.

Comment: Further I see that any positive sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that $\sum_n c_n$ converges will do.

Comment: Right, you still have to argue $f$ is strictly increasing (easy) and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, such a sequence $c_n$ will work I suppose. I thought before about finite sums of powers of $x$, but did not think about infinite sum. Thanks for this example. I suppose then there can be lot of functions, either of this type or of other type which are not Holder continuous at $0$, right? Do you know if there is any general procedure to test for such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that these functions have to be dominated by something like $x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$

False. Take the function $f(x)=e^x$ as a counterexample.

---

Also, there is no such thing as "Lipschitz continuous at some point". Lipschitz continuity is defined on a **set**, not at a point:

A function $f:X\to Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ is Lipschitz continuous if there exists some $K\in\mathbb R$ such that $d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq K\cdot d_X(x_1,x_2)$ for all pairs $x_1,x_2\in X$

Comment: By "Lipschitz continuity at a point" $x$, I am really looking at the Lipschitz condition in some neighorhood of $U$ of $x$. I am actually demanding the following condition: $$\sup_{y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta), y\ne x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}<\infty$$ for some $\delta>0$ and $U=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. In that sense note that $e^x$ is Lipschitz continuous at $0$, for any neighborhood of $0$. I am assuming similar notion of H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuity too. I am actually more focused on the local behavior of the function, than the global one.

Comment: I have changed the wording of my question a little bit to reflect the type of H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder continuity I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As it's noted by @5xum, the concepts of Lipschitz continuity and Hölder continuity are related to global behaviour of the function, but I suppose you have an intuition about local properties of $ f $.
So I give a hint to make a counterexample for a local version of your question.

It's possible that $ f $ is not Hölder continuous when restricted to any neighborhood of some point. To make a counterexample, you can construct a function that grows faster than any $ x ^ \alpha $ near $ 0 $. Such function can be defined using $ C ^ \infty $ functions that are not analytic.

If you think this hint in not helpful enough, feel free to ask me to elaborate more.

Comment: Can you  kindly give an example of such a $C^\infty$ non analytic function? I have $e^{-1/x}$ on the top of my head, but is dominated by $x^{1/2}$ near origin.

Comment: In fact any $e^{-1/x^p}$ is dominated by $x^p, \forall p>0$, .

Comment: Try using its inverse.

Comment: Do you mean inverse of $e^{-1/x}$? The inverse is $-1/(\ln x)$, which is, first of all, discontinuous at $1$, and further, is dominated by some $x^\alpha$, when $\alpha\approx 0.1$, near origin.

Comment: Of course the discontinuity is not a problem since you can define $ f $ linearly on $ [ \frac 1 2 , + \infty ) $so that it becomes continuous. The only important thing is the local behaviour of $ f $ near $ 0 $. Your claim about $ - \frac 1 { \ln x } $ being dominated by some $ x ^ \alpha $ is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong before, near $0$, $-1/(\ln(x))$ does dominate $x^{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$. I guess I was just being dumb. Thanks. Do you know if there is any particular way to check if a function has this property of being dominated by $x^\alpha $ near $0$?

Comment: I don't know about a general criterion but my idea was that a non-analytic function such that all of it's higher derivatives are zero, is dominated by every $ x ^ n $ and thus its inverse is as desired.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to find such counter-example if we restrict attention to functions that are analytic at 0?